# You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration

Tags: security, symfony, provider

i have webservice which is provider for my "regular" users. I want to use FosUserBundle for my administrators. Above is my security configuration. regular users login works with no problem, but when i want to login as admin i got this message:

"You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration. "

Here is my security configuration:

```
security:
encoders:
    Locastic\CustomUserBundle\Security\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    webservice:
        id: locastic.user_provider

firewalls:               
    main:
        pattern: ^/admin
    form_login:
        provider:               fos_userbundle
        login_path:             fos_user_security_login 
        check_path:             fos_user_security_check
        csrf_provider:          form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
    user-service:
        pattern: ^/
        logout:       
          path:   /logout
        anonymous:    true
        webservice-login:
            check_path: /prijava-provjera
            login_path: /prijavi-se
            provider: webservice
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /stanje-racuna

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to put `form_login` under a firewall ( either `main` or add another one )

form_login under main firewall :

```
firewalls:               
main:
    pattern: ^/admin
    form_login:
        provider:               fos_userbundle
        login_path:             fos_user_security_login 
        check_path:             fos_user_security_check
        csrf_provider:          form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true ....
```

form_login under another firewall

```
firewalls:               
    main:
        pattern: ^/admin
    second_firewall:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider:               fos_userbundle
            login_path:             fos_user_security_login 
            check_path:             fos_user_security_check
            csrf_provider:          form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true .....
```

Comment: Complementary information can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406446/how-does-the-login-check-path-route-work-without-default-controller-action

Comment: How to configure Fosuserbundle to use two firewalls? I followed the steps I had a the same error.

Comment: hi @zizoujab i have updated SF 2.4 to SF 2.8, unable to login. showing following runtime exception in You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration. in /var/www/html/Soundbasics_production/SoundBasics_Symfony/src/soundBasics/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php on line 270 in /login_check method.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong only in the part of check_path value.

This is your original code:

```
firewalls:               
    main:
        pattern: ^/admin
        form_login:
            provider:               fos_userbundle
            login_path:             fos_user_security_login 
            check_path:             fos_user_security_check
            csrf_provider:          form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

And you should use something like:

```
firewalls:               
    main:
        pattern: ^/admin
        form_login:
            provider:               fos_userbundle
            login_path:             fos_user_security_login 
            check_path:             /login_check
            csrf_provider:          form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

**Note** that *check_path* has as value only a string. If you use the value *fos_user_security_check* you are calling to [SecurityController.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php) class and invoking the [checkAction()](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L77) method which exactly only throws an RuntimeError Exception with the error displayed "*You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.*". So the fix is so simple that not use the value fos_user_security_check

Answer (score 1):

`pattern: ^/admin`

This is possibly where your problems start.

Try changing this back to ^/

Then change your routes for FosUserBundle

```
# app/config/routing.yml

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix: /admin

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /admin/profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /admin/register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /admin/resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /admin/profile
```

Comment: Also check the previous answer, you'll need to correct that indenting as well I think.

Answer (score 1):

In some instances, I can see that this is caused by default security settings generated when symfony is installed by composer.

In my case, in my security.yml, I had this section:

```
default:
    anonymous: ~
```

As this was working as a catch-all, it was interfering with FOSUserBundle's ability to handle the route. Just delete it or, if you have a route you've specified yourself, make sure it's not also handling the same URL path.

Comment: Yes same problem here! FOSUserBundle is not working with this section enabled.