# FOSUserBundle: configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login

Tags: symfony, configuration, routes, yaml, fosuserbundle

I download the FOSUser Bundle in my symfony project.

This is the routing file of the bundle:

```
# Manage security
fos_user_security:
    resource:  "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

# User Profil
fos_user_profile:
    resource:  "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

# Register User
fos_user_register:
    resource:  "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

# Reset User password
fos_user_resetting:
    resource:  "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetPassword

# Change User password
fos_user_change_password:
    resource:  "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /changePassword
```

Now, when I would like to go to the login page, everything works, but when I would like to connect the user, I have this error:

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using
>   form_login in your security firewall configuration.

This is my config file, security.yml:

```
security:

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: fos_user_security_login_check
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:
                path:     fos_user_security_logout
                target:   /
            anonymous:    true

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

What I am doign wrong?

Moreover, when I would like to logout I have this error:

> You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.

Comment: You will have a problem with the double encoders key

Comment: I do not see `fos_user_security_login_check` and `fos_user_security_login` defined in your routing file.

Comment: @LéoBenoist I removed the first encoder `encoders: FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt`, I have another error when I would like to logout `You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.`

Comment: @Dric512, I defined them in the main firewall here `main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: fos_user_security_login_check
                login_path: fos_user_security_login`

Comment: Yes but where are the routes for `fos_user_security_login_check` and `fos_user_security_login` defined ? 

And I am not sure you can use route names for `check_path` and `login_path`, I though that you had to use URLs, for example `/login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your `default` firewall:

```
default:
    anonymous: ~
```

It catch all your requests because firewalls are tests in the order they are defined.
So on a FOSUserBundle page like the login page, there is no `form_login` provider, nor `logout` one.

Comment: sorry to answer you just now. I have not my code with me for now, but I'll tried your suggestion asap. Thank you for reply.

Comment: No problem, hope it will help.

Comment: It's been a while, and I don't take the time to answer you (better late than never). Thank you by the way, you help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   /login
                default_target_path: /profile/
                always_use_default_target_path: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a duplicate of [You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874725/you-must-configure-the-check-path-to-be-handled-by-the-firewall-using-form-login/46870237#46870237)

Your code is wrong only in the part of check_path value.

This is your original code:

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: fos_user_security_login_check
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
```

And you should use something like:

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: fos_user_security_login_check
            login_path: /login_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
```

**Note** that *check_path* has as value only a string. If you use the value *fos_user_security_check* you are calling to [SecurityController.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php) class and invoking the [checkAction()](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L77) method which exactly only throws an RuntimeError Exception with the error displayed "*You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.*". So the fix is so simple that not use the value fos_user_security_check

Comment: Hi Shakaran, i'm also facing same issue, i have updated SF 2.4 to SF 2.8, FOSUserBundle 1.4 to 2.0 attached screenshots of security.yml and error page https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1538 , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This took me days to sort out and was such a simple solution. Hope to save someone else some time, by posting what I did. Just had to remove

```
check_path: fos_user_security_login_check
```

My security.yml looks now like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: /admin/materials/
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout: 
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
                target: /
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```